# Kernel Restarting The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel

I am facing a problem with mu jupyter notebook as it keeps dying after I execute the code below. I tried different solutions provided by the commnity but without success, including upgrading Numpy, re-installing ipykernel, ipython, and others.

I am using a 13-inch 2020 Macbook pro with processor: *2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5* and 16GB of RAM. The size of my dataset is about 292MB.

**Error Message:** *"Kernel Restarting The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically"*

***Code:***

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

# Assuming you have a list of lemmatized tokens
# tokens_lemmatized = [...]

# Join the lemmatized tokens into sentences
documents = [' '.join(tokens) for tokens in data_words]

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': documents})

# Create a CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()

# Fit and transform the text data
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(df['text'])

# Create a DataFrame from the DTM (Document-Term Matrix)
dfm = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=vectorizer.get_feature_names_out())

# Most frequent terms
top_features = dfm.sum().sort_values(ascending=False)

# Display the top 50 terms
print(top_features.head(50))
```

Comment: Please read and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The second section stresses 'Search and Research'. Did you search the error and look for what it generally said in regards to that error and Jupyter? Did you try with a smaller amount of your data?